# Uploading image using angular 4 and nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, multer

I am using angular 4 and node using multer to upload image. Everything is running fine there is no error but I dont see the file in the folder. Here is the code.

```
 <td><input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".pdf,.jpeg,.png"></td>
```

In component

```
 return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/doc/uploadfile', FormData , {headers:this.headerss}).map((res: Response)=>{
           const data=res.json();
            console.log(data);
            return data;
            }).
            catch(this.handleError);
```

It shows everything being submitted fine
[image]

Than in nodejs I am using multer

```
var upload=multer({dest: './uploads/'}).single('avatar');
               router.post('/uploadfile',  function(req, res){
                   upload(req, res, function(err){
                       if(err){
                           console.log(err);
                           return err;
                       }
                       console.log("request"+ req)
                        return  res.send("completed"+ req) 
                   })
```

There is no error everything goes fine. But I dont see any image being loaded. Please let me know how can I fix this...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove content-type and it worked fine